# Interior, boundary, and closure of intersection of two half spaces

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $c\in\mathbb{N}$ and $S=\{(x,y):f(x,y)< c< g(x,y)\}$ where $f,g$ are some function maps from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Can we find the Interior, boundary, and closure of $S$ ?

If not, for sets like this do they share some general property that can be helpful when we want to find their Interior, boundary, and closure?

**My attempts**

Here $S$ can be expressed as the intersection of two half sapces in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that
\begin{align}
S^\circ=&(\{(x,y):f(x,y)< c\}\cap\{(x,y):c< g(x,y)\})^\circ\\
=&\{(x,y):f(x,y)< c\}^\circ\cap\{(x,y):c< g(x,y)\}^\circ\\
=&\{(x,y):f(x,y)< c\}\cap\{(x,y):c< g(x,y)\}=S\\
\overline{S}=&\overline{\{(x,y):f(x,y)< c\}\cap\{(x,y):c< g(x,y)\}}\\
=&\overline{\{(x,y):f(x,y)< c\}}\cap\overline{\{(x,y):c< g(x,y)\}}\\
=&\{(x,y):f(x,y)\le c\}\cap\{(x,y):c\le g(x,y)\}\\
=&\{(x,y):f(x,y)\le c\le g(x,y)\}\\
\partial S=&\overline{S}\setminus S^\circ\\
=&\{(x,y):f(x,y)\le c\le g(x,y)\}\cap\{(x,y):f(x,y)< c< g(x,y)\}^c\\
=&\{(x,y):f(x,y)\le c\le g(x,y)\text{ and }(f(x,y)\ge c\text{ or } c\ge g(x,y))\}\\
=&\{(x,y):f(x,y)\le c\le g(x,y)\\
&\text{ and }(f(x,y)< c\text{ implies } c\ge g(x,y))\\
&\text{ and }(c<g(x,y)\text{ implies }f(x,y)\ge c)\}
\end{align}

Consider four cases

$1.f(x,y)< c< g(x,y)$ then $c\ge g(x,y)$ contradiction.

$2.f(x,y)< c= g(x,y)$ which is fine.

$3.f(x,y)= c< g(x,y)$ which is fine.

$4.f(x,y)= c= g(x,y)$ which is fine

Hence we have
$$\partial S=\{(x,y):f(x,y)< c= g(x,y)\}\cup\{(x,y):f(x,y)= c< g(x,y)\}\cup\{(x,y):f(x,y)= c= g(x,y)\}$$
This solution intuitively seems make sense to me $\dots$

If this is correct, would this solution also has a generalization to $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that

$$S=\{(x_1,\dots,x_n):f(x_1,\dots,x_n)<c<g(x_1,\dots,x_n)\}$$

And my another confusion about this is, say we have 
$$S_1=\{(x,y):f(x,y)\le c\le g(x,y)\}$$
$$S_2=\{(x,y):f(x,y)\le c< g(x,y)\}$$
$$S_3=\{(x,y):f(x,y)< c\le g(x,y)\}$$
they also share the same Interior,closure and boundary as $S$, is this correct?

Thanks for your help.